# Why yarn build does not raise error when "?" is not used for optional?

Tags: typescript, option-type

I have this expression:

```js
let pricingOption: PricingOptionType | undefined = event?.pricingOptions[pricingOptionId]
```

and `yarn build` does not raise any error, though its declaration

```js
export type ProgramDTO = {
    pricingOptions?: { [pricingOptionId: string]: PricingOptionType }
```

would reqire an extra "?." operator, like this:

```js
let pricingOption: PricingOptionType | undefined = event?.pricingOptions?.[pricingOptionId]
```

I have `reactStrictMode: true,` setting.

Question 1: What other settings I need to get relevant warnings?

Question 2: Why it is not possible to declare an optional in Typescript in the Swift style, like:

```js
let pricingOption?: PricingOptionType = event?.pricingOptions?.[pricingOptionId]
```

In Swift optionals: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

are decalred like this:

```swift
let shortForm: Int? = Int("42")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwMYIHYHMDyZgIPaoAq40AvFKgK4C2ARhHANwBQokUAGlOQN7NQCoYRCgzZcBAM4B+AFxQeUANrDkaLDnyoAkgBN5k4IgwBdefDVjNBYuwC+zB8wBmlVEgmoozgBQAPWQ4AGlVRDU89WUNjdABKPkEoABsIYCERdXEtcwyrT1toAB8oN10IZzQIXW4oPwA6UMzrVEkVXPCtPRNHZmYAej6UtMa87Nh2rJsSKGLS8srq8ggANwhUYGkGiebWkY6CLqA)

```
type PricingOptionType = number;
type X = {
    pricingOptions?: { [pricingOptionId: string]: PricingOptionType }
}

function f(x:X,pricingOptionId:string){
    let pricingOption: PricingOptionType | undefined 
      = x.pricingOptions[pricingOptionId]
                    // ^ ERROR
}
```

this does give an error.

However, if I turn **off** the *strictNullChecks* in the tsconfig/type-checking options, the error disappears - [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&alwaysStrict=false&target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwMYIHYHMDyZgIPaoAq40AvFKgK4C2ARhHANwBQokUAGlOQN7NQCoYRCgzZcBAM4B+AFxQeUANrDkaLDnyoAkgBN5k4IgwBdefDVjNBYuwC+zB8wBmlVEgmoozgBQAPWQ4AGlVRDU89WUNjdABKPkEoABsIYCERdXEtcwyrT1toAB8oN10IZzQIXW4oPwA6UMzrVEkVXPCtPRNHZmYAej6UtMa87Nh2rJsSKGLS8srq8ggANwhUYGkGiebWkY6CLqA)

Comment: Why you think my example is not complete? It seems a setting in environment make it not turn on warning?

Comment: @János - I modified my answer after finding that setting **strictNullChecks** parameter to `false` results in no error.